# covert list into another new list with new property name

Tags: reactjs, list, reduce

I have one list look like allsettings. I want to convert that list to a new list. Since I am new to react I don't have much idea, I tried by doing the below way but 1st item in the new list is always empty.

```
const [mySetting, setMySet] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const allSettings = [
      { name: "Setting1", value: true, label: 1 },
      { name: "Setting2", value: true, label: 2 },
      { name: "Setting3", value: true, label: 3 },
      { name: "Setting4", value: false, label: 4 },
      { name: "Setting5", value: true, label: 5 },
      { name: "Setting6", value: true, label: 6 },
      { name: "Setting7", value: true, label: 7 }
    ];
    const settings = [];
    const allSettingsMap = allSettings.reduce((resMap, current) => {
      settings.push(resMap);
      return {
        ...resMap,
        SettingID: current.label,
        Name: current.name,
        value: current.value
      };
    }, {});
    setMySet(settings);
  }, []);
```

//I want new list like this:

```
const newSettings = [
          { name: "Setting1", value: true, SettingID: 1 },
         { name: "Setting2", value: true, SettingID: 2 },
          { name: "Setting3", value: true, SettingID: 3 },
          { name: "Setting4", value: false, SettingID: 4 },
          { name: "Setting5", value: true, SettingID: 5 },
          { name: "Setting6", value: true, SettingID: 6 },
          { name: "Setting7", value: true, SettingID: 7 }
        ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to rename a key in your object and keeping other keys intact. For each object, you can pick `label` and rename it to `SettingID` and keep other key-values same.

```js
const allSettings = [ { name: "Setting1", value: true, label: 1 }, { name: "Setting2", value: true, label: 2 }, { name: "Setting3", value: true, label: 3 }, { name: "Setting4", value: false, label: 4 }, { name: "Setting5", value: true, label: 5 }, { name: "Setting6", value: true, label: 6 }, { name: "Setting7", value: true, label: 7 } ],
      result = allSettings.map(({label, ...other}) => ({...other, SettingID: label}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it by map on array

```js
const allSettings = [
      { name: "Setting1", value: true, label: 1 },
      { name: "Setting2", value: true, label: 2 },
      { name: "Setting3", value: true, label: 3 },
      { name: "Setting4", value: false, label: 4 },
      { name: "Setting5", value: true, label: 5 },
      { name: "Setting6", value: true, label: 6 },
      { name: "Setting7", value: true, label: 7 }
    ];
   const newAllSettings = allSettings.map(item => {
      return {
        name: item.name,
        value: item.value,
        SettingID:item.label
      };
    });
    console.log(newAllSettings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your allSettings.reduce method with this map method

```
const settings = [];

allSettings.map((setting) => {
  const item = { ...setting };
  const tempValue = item?.label;
  // delete item label
  delete item["label"];

  item["SettingID"] = tempValue;

  settings.push(item);
});
```